# Solspace FreeForm notifications

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

I'm a bit confused by the notifications set-up in Freeform. The instructions state 'The notification template used to send an email to the email value entered into this field (optional).' I selected the template and entered an email address in the field below, but an email notification is sent to the user of the form as well as the administrator following a submission. So how do I set up a notification to send to admin only? And if I wanted to create a separate notification for the user, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious, but you need to select the email field in the form settings, then select a notification from the pane on the right to send to the value in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Freeform allows you to send [email notifications 5 different ways](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/email-notifications.html#types-of-email-notifications) (all of them each being able to have their own notification templates, etc).

For **[Submitter Notifications](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/email-notifications.html#types-of-email-notifications)** specifically, you would follow these instructions:

> Email notifications can be sent to the user submitting the form using the Email field type. This is often used to send an email confirmation for the user. To setup:
>
> - In Field Editor (Freeform -> Fields) or Composer Quick Field (Add New Field button at left), create a new field of the [Email field type](http://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v2/overview/fields-field-types.html#fields-email).
>     In Composer interface for the form, drag that field into field layout.
> - Click on field inside field layout and look over to the Property Editor (right column).
> - Select and/or add an email template.
>
> When the form submitter enters their email address in this field, Freeform will use that email address to send the email notification to.