# Freeform Email Notification HTML template not found

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

I have set up Freeform Email Notifications, but I need them to be `HTML` templates within my templates folder to access the `entry` that the form is attached to. The problem is that Freeform keeps giving me the following error when loading the template:

> Email notification template with ID test.html not found
>   {"form":"Accepted"} []

- My test.html is within /templates/ in my Craft Folder.
- My form lies within the folder /templates/submissions/
- It has the default header config from the docs.

This is how I'm calling my dynamic Notification:

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("accepted", {
  overrideValues: {
    entry: entry.id,
  },
  dynamicNotification: {
    recipients: entry.author.email,
    template: "test.html"
  }
}).render() }}
```

Comment: It looks like it cant find your template 'test.html'. Depending upon how you set up the templates free-form can be quite a beast. Have you specified the email template in Admin Notifications? I'm not sure you can mix and match on the form between database and twig templates.If you installed the default templates then the routes are added for those. These routes usually give the default path where free-from looks for templates and these are specified in settings->routes too. So maybe the route is wrong hence the error or it is misconfigured on the form?

Comment: and this: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21012/solspace-freeform-notifications?rq=1